# Encrypt a large file using with public and private key

Tags: php, laravel, phpseclib

I need to encrypt files **(max. size 10MB)** using a **public key** after uploading process. I have tried to encrypt with **PHPSecLib**, but the performance with large files is horrible.

Comment: https://arjunphp.com/encrypt-decrypt-files-using-php/ ?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. This solution is like openssl_encrypt. For the encryption you need only one key. I need a solution with two keys. One key for encrypt and the second for decrypt like openssl_public_encrypt, openssl_private_decrypt

Comment: You want to use a hybrid cryptosystem as described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem . http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/interop.html#seal,p1phpseclib,p2phpseclib is an example of how to do this with phpseclib but really I'd just use libsodium: https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/05-publickey-crypto.md#crypto-box phpseclib is great if you have to interoperate with a legacy system using legacy crypto algorithms but if you don't then I'd use libsodium.

Comment: The problem with phpseclib (and OpenSSL) is that it gives you choices and you can make the wrong choices. libsodium takes away your ability to make choices and thereby make mistakes.